# How does this expression simplify into the following?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMqfc.png)

I dont understand the steps taken that transform the expression into what they did.
this is the url where i got it from:[http://www.ms.uky.edu/~ma138/Spring18/Lectures/Lecture_14_answers.pdf](http://www.ms.uky.edu/%7Ema138/Spring18/Lectures/Lecture_14_answers.pdf)

Comment: Multiply both sides by $M^2$

Comment: Can you use MathJax for to write your problem in the post?

Comment: the right side makes sense but the left is within a parentheses being squared. Also im new here so sorry the image is a link. Il try to edit